# how to calculate the average value with map filter and reduce functions in kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, filter, reduce

I would like to calculate the average of a value into a collection using map, filter and reduce functions in kotlin.

I saved the data in this way:

```
data class  Track(
val id:String,
var name: String,
var popularity: Int,
var duration: Int,
var explicit: Int,
var artist: String,
var idArtist: String,
var releaseDate: String,
var danceability: Float,
var energy: Float,
var key: Float,
var loudness: Float,
var mode: Float,
var speechness: Float,
var acousticness: Float,
var instrumentalness: Float,
var liveness: Float,
var valence: Float,
var tempo: Float,
var timeSignature: Float
```

)

and i grouped the data by year in this way:

```
fun group_tracks_by_year(tracks: MutableList<Track>): Map<String, List<Track>> {

    val grouped_tracks = tracks.groupBy { it.releaseDate.split('-')[0] }.toSortedMap()
    return  grouped_tracks
}
```

For example i'd like to calculate the average tempo per year, i'm trying to manipulate the map collection `Map<String, List<Track>>` with the [map function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#zip) but i'm not able to manipulate the key-value record.

Comment: Try breaking down the problem down into simpler steps. If you already the numbers in a simple array, how would you calculate their average?

Comment: thanks. 
i would like to do it without breaking down the problem down. i know that is possibile to solve the same problem with some other languages like rust, python etc... so i have to do the same stuff with kotlin.
So probably the solution will be or very easy or it is impossible

Comment: "I would like to do it without breaking down the problem down." Why would you want to *not* do that??? Literally all of programming is breaking complex problems into small problems and solving those ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `filter` or `reduce` for this. You can use `sumOf`.

And you should use `mapValues`, because `map` returns a List rather than a Map with the same keys.

```
val tempoAveragesByYear = tracksByYear.mapValues { (year, tracks) -> 
    (tracks.sumOf { it.tempo.toDouble() } / tracks.size ).toFloat()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and it is even easier than i expect